# Apache Mahout - Generating a recommendation using EuclideanDistanceSimilarity

Tags: mahout, euclidean-distance, mahout-recommender

I have been using the Mahout library to implement a recommendation algorithm. I have used the `EuclideanDistanceSimilarity` class and so far my results seem fine.

My `DataModel` currenty consists of 500 ratings for 100 items which are rated on a scale of 1 to 5 such as

customer  itemID  rating

____1 ____2_____8

However the [Apache Mahout API's](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout-0.7-cdh4.3.2/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/EuclideanDistanceSimilarity.html) states that "*Note that the distance isn't normalized in any way; it's not valid to compare similarities computed from different domains (different rating scales, for example). Within one domain, normalizing doesn't matter much as it doesn't change ordering.*"

Will this impact the validity/reliability of my results as I capture more customers and items?

Answer (score 1):

The important part of your citation is the **domain**:
As long as you add more data such as customers and items from the same system *(domain)* using the same 5-star rating scale, there's no need to 
 normalize data.

If you started to add **data from other systems** using e.g. a *7-star rating*, you'd somehow had to ***normalize*** these ratings in order to achieve comparability with your existing 5-star scale.

Let me add a few more words about rating based recommendation:

In general your approach is fine. The only problem with ratings is, that users tend to rate quite differently. One user may submit a "3" for an item she likes while another would assign a "5". Some recommenders therefore experiment with other approaches - e.g. converting numeric ratings to boolean, where any rating would be seen as a general "interest" towards the item.

I can highly recommend to capture a few statistics about your dataset - e.g. the average rating. If this should be close to 1 or 5 (meaning most ratings are either very bad or very good and not equally distributed) you might want to give the boolean approach a try...